# Vertex paint colors problem

Tags: vertex-paint

I am doing a really low poly style for a project that I am working on. We are using vertex paint mode only with physically based rendering in Unity. My issue is occurring during the vertex painting step. When I go to paint a certain color on the selected face It shows the correct color while I am painting it but when I select a different face to paint, the previous one changes to a darker valued color. Ive looked through all the settings but I cant figure out why it is doing this. please help.

Comment: What is even more bizarre is when I view the entire object with the face selection masking for painting turned off and use the color picker it gives me the correct color, bit if I do it with the masking turned on it gives me a completely different color